# Eclipse shortcut for command sequence

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a way to run a sequence of commands by a single shortcut in eclipse, i.e. `F11` should clean the project and then build and run the application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/ lets you record macros which can be assigned to shortcuts in the usual way.